# Output lines that include punctuations in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Given a text file, I want to output lines that include at least one of the following punctuations: `! . ?` in Bash.

I've tried doing that for the point `.` first but so far I haven't succeeded yet.

```
sed '/^\.*$/d' file
sed '/^\.+$/d' file
sed '/^[.]/d' file
```

Could you please help me on this problem? Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: So what those `sed` do is remove all lines except the one having those punctuations? That is your goal?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, that is exactly my goal.

Comment: `grep -E '[.!?]' file`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you so much! That works for me! Could you please post the answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all lines except those with `!` `.` or `?`:

```
sed '/[!.?]/!d'
```

or alternatively output only lines that include at least one of those characters:

```
sed -n '/[!.?]/p'
```

About your tries:

```
sed '/^\.*$/d' file
```

The `^` and `$` match the beginning and ending of a line. It removes all lines that have zero or more dots and dots only.

```
sed '/^\.+$/d' file
```

Same as above, but one or more. It removes all lines that have one or more dots and only dots.

```
sed '/^[.]/d' file
```

This would remove all lines start with a single dot. The `[` and `]` specify OR relation, so for example `[.?]` - would be dot or question mark. One character inside `[` `]` is equal to just that character.

Comment: I tried your answer but it keeps only the lines without any punctuations in the list (which in fact, are those that I would like to remove). Thank you so much for explaining the lines that I tried!

Comment: Och right, it should be inverted! Edited ; ) No no, that's not right. Now it's ok.

Comment: You could use the POSIX `PUNCT` character class with the advantage that it deals with locale settings for language specific punctuation characters. so: `sed -n '/[[:PUNCT:]]/p'`

Comment: @LéaGris Thank you for your suggestion! However, I just want only the punctuations used to end a sentence like `.`, `!` and `?` while the POSIX `PUNCT` has many other characters.